# Large preferences (plist) files

Tags: macos, plist

Browsing through my recent Yosemite backup I noticed that two of the largest files were `com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` (78 MB) and `com.apple.recentitems.plist` (10 MB). Both files are located in `~/Library/Preferences`.

Investigating `com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` yields that the following key holds a huge amount of data under the key: `systemitems` > `VolumesList` > `Bookmark` > `data`

Is it normal for plist files to become so large? What kind of data is this (icon previews?) and why are the files so large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property List (`plist`) files can grow to large sizes. Ten megabytes is large for preferences but not extreme.

#### Reasonable Size

Apple's developer documentation mentions that preferences sync'd with iCloud have an [upper limit of 1 MB](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/index.html):

> The total amount of space available in your app’s key-value store, for a given user, is 1 MB. There is a per-key value size limit of 1 MB, and a maximum of 1024 keys.

#### Bookmarks

The sidebar lists and recent items content you mention are bookmarks. [Bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW34) are encoded blobs of data used by OS X to locate a specific file or folder. A bookmark frequently contains more information than just a path; information such as security rights and means to locate the original file should it move or be renamed.

Comment: Thanks - so would you say my 78 MB plist file is dorked somehow?

Comment: 78 MB is large but not huge in a world where Macs have 4+ GiB of RAM. If you want to reclaim the space, delete the file, log out and log back in. You will loose your Finder's customised sidebar selection.